# How to understand this NN architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-neural-networks, papers

I was reading a paper [Multi-Agent Reinforcement Learning for Adaptive
User Association in Dynamic mmWave Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.09066.pdf) and I was stuck understanding the deep neural network architecture that was used. The authors gave it in Fig. 3 (on top of page 6) and they state the following (on page 9):

> This architecture comprises 2 multi-layers perceptron (MLP) of 32 hidden units, one RNN layer (a long short memory term - LSTM) layer with 64 memory cells followed by another 2 MLPs of 32 hidden units. The network then branches off in two MLPs of 16 hidden units to construct the duelling network.

According to Fig. 3 there is one MLP, one RNN and one MLP. So why the authors said 2 MLPs?

Assuming it is 2 MLPs, does this mean we have 2 hidden layers of 32 neurons each? So, at the end we will have:

*one input layer - one hidden layer with 32 neurons - another hidden layer with 32 neurons - one RNN layer with 64 cells - one hidden layer with 32 neurons - another hidden layer with 32 neurons - one hidden layer with 16 neurons - another hidden layer with 16 neurons - one output layer.*